# Rails production: Directory index forbidden by Options directive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, http-status-code-403

I'm working on deploying my rails app using apache and passenger on a virtual server that I'm managing via Virtualmin.  All of this is being hosted on an Ubuntu 12.04 VPS.

Anyway, I'm getting the following error.

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

At first, when this occurred, I was getting the error:

> Premature end of script headers

in my virtual host error log and a key error in my apache error log.  Both of these went away though once I updated my `config/secrets.yml` file.  The 403 error, however has remained.  Additionally, the virtual server error log had the error:

> Directory index forbidden by Options directive

Additionally I've made sure that my public_html directory (and all of is subdirectories) is the right user for apache.  I've checked the production error log, and apache error log and haven't seen anything come out when I load the page.

Any ideas as to what I should try?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This question is not really Rails related, as I believe there is an error in your server setup. Looks like your web server doesn't really tries to call the rails app, instead it just try to list the directory. That said, please post your Apache's VirtualHost definition, but bear in mind, this kind of question rather belongs to serverfault.